# How to download all file types using php header

Tags: php, header, mime-types

I want to make a force download file to download files from server with saved urls in database and also i don't want to show download links to clients and i know it's possible to make links hidden with htaccess but i want to make limit my links just for clients that paid the cost for each link.

I used php header() function to do my target but the problem is related to mime types i have below script and **i don't want to define mime type for each url(based file type and extension) in array or something like that, because i have a wide various of file types in my files and i want to share this files with my users and i can't define one mime type for each file type separately**.

I need to a good function to get mime types from file name (automatic) like mime_content_type() but it's related to a php extension and i don't have access to php.ini in my sharing host and also this function is deprecated.

**Below codes working good with some extensions like mp3 and zip files but mp4 files that downloaded via this script are damaged and not playable in media player**

php codes:

```
<?php
require 'includes/connection.php';
$connection=newconnection();
if(isset($_GET['fileid']) && is_numeric($_GET['fileid'])){
$file_id=input_security($_GET['fileid']);
$linkque=mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM download_segments WHERE ds_id='".$file_id."'");
$checkexist=mysqli_num_rows($linkque);
$f_row=mysqli_fetch_array($linkque);

if($checkexist==0){
    echo 'Invalid file id';
}else if($checkexist>=1 && $f_row['payment_model']=="free"){
    $path=$f_row['url'];
    $sep_parts = pathinfo($path);
    $file_name  = $sep_parts['basename'];
    $file_ext   = $sep_parts['extension'];
    if (file_exists($path)) {   

        $mimetypes = array(
        "avi" => "video/x-msvideo",
        "exe" => "application/octet-stream",
        "mp4" => "video/mp4",
        "zip" => "application/zip",
        "mp3" => "audio/mpeg",
        "mpg" => "video/mpeg"
        );
        $mimedefault = "video/mp4";

        $mtype=isset($mimetypes[$file_ext]) ? $mimetypes[$file_ext] : $mimedefault;
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header("Content-Type: " . $mtype);
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($path).'"');
    //header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($path) );
    //header("Pragma: no-cache");
    //header('Expires: 0');
    //header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    //header('Pragma: public');

    readfile($path);
    exit;
    }else{
    echo 'not exist';
    }
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Take a look at [`finfo_file`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php) It can return the MIME type of a file.

Comment: Thank you @Barmar i'm going to check this function.

Comment: And also the problem in damaging mp4 files are still. i need a solution to resolve this problem please.

Comment: One question at a time. But I can't see anything there that would damage any files.

Comment: Mr @Barmar I don't have any problem with other extensions except mp4 files. I checked on various operating systems like ubuntu and windows with lamp.

Comment: The problem was about read permission in the file .in ubuntu and it's working now